# how i fire custom event from HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

currently i am using code like this

```
// Create the event.
var event = document.createEvent('Event');

// Define that the event name is 'swiping'.
event.initEvent('swiping', true, true);

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('swiping', function (e) {
  // e.target matches elem
}, false);

// target can be any Element or other EventTarget.
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

to handle element swiping

how i fire this event from HTML element ? (like `<div on-swiping="function-name"></div>` OR PolymerJS custom elements events `on-click`, `on-tap`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The key `elem.dispatchEvent(event);`

You can defined a custom event using `elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) {`

And when user `click` (or `tab`) you trigger that event using `elem.dispatchEvent(event);`

And the full demo is:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#test');

// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) {
  alert(elem.innerText);
}, false);

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var event = new Event('build');
  // Dispatch the event.
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
<button>Buttons</button>
```

[Mozila docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tifite)

Comment: i am looking `<button on-build="function-name">Buttons</button>` u can see polymer doing custom events in this manner

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need to trigger a custom event using `polymer` instead of regular `javascript`?

Comment: i want to call custom event build from HTML element like this  `<button onbuild="function-name">Buttons</button>` it will call custom event `build` event handler

Comment: Using `Polymer` or not? Why should you need the attribute `onbuild`?